# How to change the page title with title from backend

Tags: angular, page-title

I want to change the page title located in the index.html  with a title from the backend. I used angular Title service but this didn't solve the problem,
this is my code so far in the app component:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.page = this.visuals.pageTitle;
    this.visualsService.getVisuals().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.visuals = res;
      this.title.setTitle(this.visuals.pageTitle);
    });
  }
```

I think i cannot use dataBinding since the page title is statically located in index.html. knowing that the subscription is working correctly, is there any other solution ?

Comment: Is the subscription executing?

Comment: Otherwise you can do it using vanilla javascript `document.title = 'hello'`

Comment: @AmineDaly, can you clarify which title you are referring to? The title in index.html usually refers to title showing in browser tab's title. Or is it a title rendering within angular component?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your subscription is correctly receiving the data from the backend, this should be enough to make the title receive the correct data:

TS:

```
      title: string = '';
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.visualsService.getVisuals().subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.visuals = res;
          this.title = this.visuals.pageTitle;
        });
      }
```

HTML:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

Comment: The problem is that the page title is statically in index.html so I can't bind the data. subscription is working correctly by the way

Comment: If it is static in index.html, where I declared it first, instead of empty, make it with the text that is statically chosen!

Comment: I made a mistake, I assigned the response to the visuals after setting the title so visuals.pageTitle became undefined. Now it works correctly. thanks for helping

Comment: I am glad u got it fixed! :)